# Visual Studio: Use csv file for "Find Text" validation in web performance test

Tags: visual-studio

I can use csv files to enter data into input field after a test is recorded. I was wondering if csv file could be used for "Find Text" validation field. I don't see options to add csv file so I have directly hardcode text be checked. If I could add a csv file then I would just need to change the csv file once the website texts are changed. Could this be done by using codedUI test?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields of a data source can be used in many places within a Web Performance Test. There are two main ways.

In the properties panel for the call of the validation rule, click in the value field for the required property. You should get a box allowing the data source field to be chosen.

Alternatively enter text similar to the following into the field

```
{{DataSource1.YourFileName#csv.FieldName}}
```

Note the doubled curly braces `{{` and `}}` around the full data source string. You can also add extra text to this sort of entry, eg

```
Some text{{DataSource1.YourFileName#csv.FieldName}}and even more text
```

Comment: BTW, is there a way to access particular value from the csv file? Something like {{DataSource1.YourFileName#csv.FieldName.LINE_NUMBER}}?

Comment: @user1562442 The current data row can be changed by program, but I cannot find the method at the moment. This does not allow one row to be read and then normal reading resumed. I suggest you write a new question to explain what you want and what you have tried.